# How to know which connection is PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager closing?

Tags: java, httpclient, connection-pooling

I'm implementing a Java class that extends PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager and every time the methods closeExpiredConnections and closeIdleConnections are executed I need to know which connections are being closed so I can notify an obvserver class with this information.

This is the code I have at the moment:

```
@Override
    public void closeExpiredConnections() {
        Set<HttpRoute> closedRoutes = new HashSet<>();

        // Enumerate over all connections and collect routes of the expired ones
        super.enumAvailable(entry -> {
            if (entry.isExpired(System.currentTimeMillis())) {
                closedRoutes.add(entry.getRoute());
            }
        });

        // Close the expired connections
        super.closeExpiredConnections();

        // Notify for each closed connection
        for (HttpRoute route : closedRoutes) {
            notifyConnectionDestroyed(route);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void closeIdleConnections(long idletime, TimeUnit tunit) {
        Set<HttpRoute> closedRoutes = new HashSet<>();
        long idleTimeoutMillis = tunit.toMillis(idletime);

        // Enumerate over all connections and collect routes of the idle ones
        super.enumAvailable(entry -> {
            if (entry.getUpdated() + idleTimeoutMillis < System.currentTimeMillis()) {
                closedRoutes.add(entry.getRoute());
            }
        });

        // Close the idle connections
        super.closeIdleConnections(idletime, tunit);

        // Notify for each closed connection
        for (HttpRoute route : closedRoutes) {
            notifyConnectionDestroyed(route);
        }
    }
```

But it is not working. Every time the loop `for (HttpRoute route : closedRoutes)` is executed, closedRoutes is empty even when I know that it should have at least one HttpRoute in it.